# How to convert multi-byte punctuations to single byte ones with PHP?

Tags: php, multibyte, punctuation

For example,both ， and , are commas,but the first one takes 2 byte,while the second one only 1.

How to convert the 2 byte one to 1 byte?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`iconv`](http://php.net/iconv) with the translit option (e.g., `ASCII/TRANSLIT` or `ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT`, etc. depending on how you serve your content). I haven't tried this out, but I believe it will work.

If you're not sure what the incoming charset will be, you probably want to use [`mb_detect_encoding`](http://php.net/mb_detect_encoding) to detect it, because `iconv` will freak out if it encounters a character it doesn't expect.

You may wish to read [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) for a painless intro to the subject, if you're unfamiliar with charsets.

Comment: Reread my post, and the manual page. You have to be sure you're specifying the correct input encoding, and do ASCII/**translit**.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`iconv()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) with the correct input and output character sets.